# How to secure data in production environment

Tags: security

I have an enterprise application running that uses both MySQL and Mongodb datastores. My development team all have ssh access to the machine in order to perform application releases, maintenance etc. I recently raised a risk in the business when users started storing highly sensitive data on the application that the developers have indirect access to this data which caused a bit of a storm and have now been mandated with securing the data so that it is not accessible. To me this does not seem possible because if the application has access to the database then a developer with access to the machine and application source will always be able to access the data. I am sure I am not the only one who has this issue. Please advise me on how this is being done in other corporates.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the appropriate venue for this type of question.  Also, any response would be opinion.

Comment: Where is a more appropriate forum then? I am not looking for opinion, I am looking for others are currently handling this!

Comment: I usually don't like pointing people to [programmers.SE] or [security.SE] when I'm not sure their question will be well received there, but those sites *might* be a better place. Consider checking out their scope or asking on their meta if this question would fit. Don't ask how others are doing it; ask for something that can be objectively answered with a limited number of answers.

Comment: The simple solution.  Don't store sensitive information in a database if your not willing to encrypt that sensitive information and prevent developers from accessing that data.  **If its client data then the client should be the only one that can view the data.**  This means the encryption method should use the client's authentication session to decrypt the data.  If there is malformed data for a single customer that causes a problem, you deal with it at that time, by having the customer grant you access to the account.

Comment: Wish I knew why people keep downvoting the question?

Comment: @ClintonBosch - My personal reason is because its not on topic here at Superuser.  It also appears you are asking this question before you seem to have done a great deal of research on your part.  **I only answer and upvote objective questions.**

Comment: I have never asked this question before on this forum??? I have now re-asked the question on the programmers and SI Stack exchange sites based on the feedback from slhk. I am not asking you for an upvote, simply asking why you feel it deserves a downvote, do you downvote everything that you feels doesn't deserve an upvote, if it doesn't interest you, why not just not vote at all?

Comment: I think this question is relevant for the community. It might be better asked in the Information Security stack though. As for the formulation of the question: it will be better received if you ask a *specific* question instead of a *general* advise.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the principle of "[separation of concerns](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)": let developers develop (on the D and T environments of a [DTAP roadmap](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production)) and support employees manage the A and P environments. In general, the support employee adheres to the same privacy policy rules and agreements as a "normal" application user. Setup representative, but dummy data on the D, T and A environments. This way, your developers can't access real-life data (which is as it should be).

For a more elaborate explanation, see any advanced test management methodology, such as [TMAP](http://www.tmap.net/).

Comment: Thanks, yes you could get support engineers to handle production releases, but that doesn't really solve your problem does it? It just means they have access to the database?